# Android Google Maps API - Show Restaurants, etc

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Does the Google maps API for Android have the ability to show things like 'all the restaurants' or 'all the restrooms' in a given radius? I doubt the API includes this functionality but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't provide this functionality

Answer (score 2):

You can use the google places api for that :

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following url to get the nearby places based on your current latitude, longitude and radius.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=11.777232,12.21234&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cousins&key=[Your google map api Key]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=11.777232,12.21234&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cousins&key=%3CYour%20google%20map%20api%20Key%3E)